# How to use ffmpeg in Android to load a specific frame from a server-based video

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

dependency i am using for ffmpeg

```
 implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4.LTS'
```

i just need frame of particular second from video base on server and load it frame to imageview without storing it

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) is what you are looking for

regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34533923)